# Building aggregation operation over date using Spring and DateFromString

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection with the following document :

```
{
  "observation": {
    "temporalExtent": [
      {
        "dateBeg": ISODate("2002-07-28T20:47:00.000+02:00"),
        "dateEnd": ISODate("2003-09-13T16:17:00.000+02:00")
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make the following aggregation operation that should return the document above but I can't figure out what's wrong and why the document is not found.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "observation.temporalExtent": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "dateBeg": {
          "$gte": {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "1892-01-05T23:50:39.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Any idea? You can play with [this config here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hsKf14OIk-A)

### Edit

The aggregation operation `$dateFromString`is generated by Spring-data-mongodb [DateOperators.DateFromString fromString(Object value)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/DateOperators.DateFromString.html#fromString-java.lang.Object-) method. I'd like to know why I'm misusing this operator or another way to generate the same operation with `$date` or `ISODate` constructor as mentionned by @arsendavtyan and @mani.

```
Criteria.where("dateBeg")
  .lte(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromString(tmpExtent.getString("fromDate")))
  .lte(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromString(tmpExtent.getString("toDate")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround that prevents the use of `$dateFromString` operator.

The String representation of the date are parsed into [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)

```
JSONObject tmpExtent = (JSONObject) item;
Instant from = Instant.parse(tmpExtent.getString("fromDate"));
Instant to = Instant.parse(tmpExtent.getString("toDate"));
```

The Criteria is constructed  like:

```
Criteria.where("dateBeg").lte(from).lte(to)
```

And the query made to mongoDB looks like  @arsendavtyan first solution.

`{ "dateBeg" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2011-01-31T23:00:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2019-02-21T23:00:00.000Z"}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `value.dateString` with `$date` or just use `ISODate` instead of `String`

Option 1

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "observation.temporalExtent": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "dateBeg": {
          "$gte": {
             "$date": "1892-01-05T23:50:39.000Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Option 2

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "observation.temporalExtent": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "dateBeg": {
          "$gte": ISODate("1892-01-05T23:50:39.000Z")
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try running the

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "observation.temporalExtent": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "dateBeg": {
          "$gte": new ISODate("1892-01-05T23:50:39.000Z")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

> Try running using mongoshell or Robo Mongo , Mongoplayground throw error for newIsoDate()